# How much data can be in a LocalSettings container

Tags: uwp, winjs

In one of my apps, I'm using Dexie (IndexedDb), but it's actually much slower and more troublesome than I expected it to be, and after some experimentation I'm considering switching to using `LocalSettings` containers

My first dexie table represents Items and it has about 85,000 rows, with columns Description, ItemNo, ItemCode, Category, Price and 'DealPrice'

The second table is for barcodes and it has 98,000 rows with columns BarcodeNo, ItemNo and ItemCode

If I use a `LocalSettings` container for the items and a container for the barcodes, will that be too much data for `LocalSettings` to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalSettings` do not have a specified limit, but they are actually serialized as a file in the application data folder. Hence I would not expect using them would be more performant than an actual database. They are more suited for things like "preferences" or configuration, which is changed or queried infrequently. Actually, [I have written](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi-2vHI6oHjAhXSoFwKHfvaCHoQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.mzikmund.com%2F2017%2F02%2Fuwp-application-settings-performance%2F&usg=AOvVaw2BzgqJqTx__muzt7csZ6sI) about the fact that accessing settings itself has a certain cost and caching is necessary.

I would suggest considering SQLite or [LiteDB](https://www.litedb.org/). Both should be very efficient as long as the you manipulate the data efficiently.

### Update

I didn't notice this question was tagged for winjs, not for C#. Both solutions suggested could be used in HTML+JS UWP app as well, but would require another layer of indirection (a C#-based Windows Runtime Component). In this case I would suggest trying to investigate the reason why IndexedDb is slow for you (as 100,000 entries should still be reasonably performant). IndexedDb as a native API should have great performance.

Comment: Are there any tutorials on getting either of those up and going with a Javascript+HTML UWP app?

Comment: I see, I didn't notice you mentioned WinJS, sorry about it. I would suggest creating a new question talking directly about the inefficiency you are seeing with IndexedDb first, to confirm if the problem is actually something which cannot be improved by some improved logic. Otherwise, both SQLite and LiteDB should be usable in WinJS app, but I am afraid there is no tutorial available. The process would require you to build a Windows Runtime component to communicate with these.

Comment: I would really suggest asking specifically about the IndexedDb performance first, I truly expect it should be possible to improve it.